# What does the % sign in sequelize.js $like operator mean?

Tags: sql, sequelize.js

Reference: [Sequelize-Docs](http://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/querying/#operators)

```
$like: '%hat',         // LIKE '%hat'
$notLike: '%hat'       // NOT LIKE '%hat'
$iLike: '%hat'         // ILIKE '%hat' (case insensitive) (PG only)
$notILike: '%hat'      // NOT ILIKE '%hat'  (PG only)
```

---

I'm trying to understand / find information on to the definition of `%` in the $like operators. Is this specifically postgres? - It could be a wildcard syntax but isn't the `*` usually reserved for that?

I understand it's usage as

```
Model.find({
  where: {
    $like: 'somestring'
  }
})
```

First impression:
It doesn't appear to be a regex, nor does it seem relevant to a PG operator (i.e. modulus). Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a percent sign (%) matches any sequence of zero or more characters

e.g.. `%hat` would match `that`, `aspokathat` or `hat`;

ref: [postgres-docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-matching.html)